# Обновление с 6 до 7

Tags: linux, centos, update

Подскажите как лучше обновить прод с CentOS 6 до 7? Данных очень много (несколько терабайт), но есть бэкапы (правда восстанавливать придется очень долго если-что). Говорят что лучше заново систему переустанавливать, но ведь там много софта, все настроено... Заново все разворачивать это очень долго и сложно, поэтому хотелось-бы просто обновить. Пытался сделать вот по первой же [инструкции](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/upgrade-from-centos-6-to-centos-7.html) с гугла. Но это вылилось в кучу ошибок в конце (после `preupg`):

```
Assessment finished (time 02:44s)
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 40 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/security-guide.xsl
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 41 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/oval-report.xsl
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl"
compilation error: file /usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl line 42 element import
xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/openscap/xsl/sce-report.xsl
OpenSCAP Error:: Could not parse XSLT file '/usr/share/preupgrade/xsl/preup.xsl' [oscapxml.c:416]
Unable to open file /root/preupgrade/result.html
Usage: preupg [options]

preupg: error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/preupgrade/result.html'
```

Пытался чинить по [этой](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59763) инструкции, но в итоге у меня этот `preupg` вообще пропал куда-то... Сейчас восстановил систему из бэкапа (тестирую на не основной машине поменьше - у меня их две) и не знаю пока что еще попробовать.

Comment: Что вам нужно от 7-го линукса, что вы готовы ради этого угробить прод?

Comment: @defrag Ну во первых в принципе неплохо бы обновиться уже. Т.к. у 6 версии скоро поддержка кончится... А во вторых у меня не запустился Qt там. Да и не собираюсь я его гробить - я же сказал есть бэкапы.

Comment: Займитесь лучше планом миграции, а не апгрейда, иначе бэкап замучаете.

Comment: @defrag что куда мигрировать? О чем вообще речь? О_о О переустановке с нуля?

Comment: Речь о том, что надо очень хорошо понимать, что произойдет в результате апгрейда системы, какие изменения в ней произойдут и как на все это отреагирует работающее ПО. Вы знаете ответы на эти вопросы? 7-я версия линукса - это не апгрейд 6.7 на 6.8. И иногда приходится забивать на "хочется" и "Заново все разворачивать очень долго и сложно". Я не отговариваю вас от апгрейда, я пока сильно сомневаюсь в успехе вашего предприятия.

Comment: @defrag да что вы ходите вокруг да около? Если что-то пойдет не так я откачусь. Мне просто нужны какие-то рабочие инструкции.

Comment: Инструкция в вашей первой ссылке вполне рабочая, также оф.сайт Центоси предлагает такой же алгоритм с теми же утилитами https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool Пробуйте.

Comment: @defrag я же сказал в чем была проблема когда я делал по той инструкции.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос стратегии миграции - дело индивидуальное. У нас в своё время стояла подобная же проблема, понятно что можно было с 5.11 плавно переползти на 6, потом на 7.

Но в итоге например в нашей практике прижился не подход с обновлением серверов, а миграция.

> но ведь там много софта, все настроено

С учётом того, что у нас уже давно внедрен ansible и нет никаких проблем собрать абсолютно идентичное окружение.

Подымается новая виртуалка (две, три, десять - по необходимости), настраивается абсолютно идентичное окружение и проводится тестирование. Успешно - обдумывается момент, связанный с миграцией данных (например, базы данных в моменты минимального использования системы пользователями).

Рекомендую и вам в этом же направлении присматриваться.

Ваш подход тоже имеет право на жизнь... тут два самых больших риска - это забыть сделать бекап/контрольную точку на виртуалке, чтобы можно было вернуться (тоже могу много рассказать страшилок из своего опыта) и риск того, что проблемы всплывут через неделю после обновления, когда откатываться назад будет поздно и только вперёд.