# Как сохранить все установленные пакеты и их конфиги

Tags: linux, archlinux, автоматизация

Как сохранить все установленные пакеты и их конфигурации, для того что бы в будущем я мог на свежеустановленной системе развернуть привычное мне окружение?

Хочу что бы работало это так: установил линукс, поставил sddm, openbox, cairo-compmgr, fpanel, nautilus, настроил все под себя, каким-то образом упаковал это (в файл например) и при желании, на свежей системе мог бы установить все перечисленные выше пакеты с теми же конфигами, с которыми они были упакованы.

Это возможно на archlinux? Под убунту, судя по всему, есть утилита Aptitude, которая это умеет (на счёт переноса конфигов не уверен)

Comment: Попробуйте ansible. Написали плейбук - и можно сколько угодно раз запускать. Под конкретно archlinux не гонял, но вижу, что и под ним есть.

Comment: @AK прочитал статью на хабре (https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/196620/), похоже это приложение для управления парком компьютеров. Мне нужно это для дома. Хочу собрать приятный мне линукс и иметь возможность легко воспроизводить сборку.

Comment: домашний каталог свой сохраните. там и история команд оболочки находится (это по поводу «какие пакеты устанавливались»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin и что вы предлагаете? Жать мне "вверх-enter" при установке новой системы? Проще написать shell скрипт устанавливающий нужные пакеты. А что с конфигами? На одном ПК у меня пользователя зовут Bob, а на другом Alice, мне домашние папки переименовывать? А если в них есть лишние файлы? Ваш совет не эффективен и не имеет смысла

Comment: Это приложение для парка компьютеров, но разве что-то мешает его применять и к одному компьютеру? Он от этого не становится менее удобным. Вы приводите пример "на одном ПК пользователя зовут Bob, на другом Alice" -- уииии, вы реально пришли к управлению конфигурациями и переменная "имя пользователя ПК"  в системе управления конфигурациями -- это самое то для вас. А положив эти файлы в git вы ещё будете видеть, когда, что и как менялось. Это настолько восхитительная вещь, что вас непременно затянет. Попробуйте, обязательно попробуйте!

Comment: Как сохоранить список пакетов в арче - хз, но если `/home` - в отдельном разделе, то как говорил @alexanderbarakin всё становится легче. Плюс сохранить `/etc` и `/var/spool/cron`. А потом в нужных местах просто поменять значения на актуальные, раз они чуть отличаются. Ой. Кажется я придумал систему управления конфигурацией.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно двигаться в сторону управления конфигурациями.

ПО, которое для этого предназначено – это ansible, chef, puppet. Лично я первым поставил ansible (показалось, что про него больше информации в сети), попробовал и... и на ней и остался, другое пробовать не стал.

У меня была виртуальная машина с чистым свежеустановленным Centos (разумеется, с контрольной точкой, к которой я мог вернуться в считанные секунды) и машина, на которой я начинал писать плейбук.

Поменял пару строчек, вернулся к чистой ОС, применил – посмотрел, устраивает ли. Устраивает – коммитим изменения скрипта в git, не устраивает – переписываем плейбук и повторяем цикл.

Я могу гарантировать, что конфигурация, которую вы будете применять - будет гарантированно одинаковой (то, чего вы добиваетесь).

Плейбуков можете написать несколько, например, можно выделить отдельный плейбук для настройки общего софта для машины (скажем, fail2ban), а отдельно выделить отдельно скрипт настройки админской учётки и своей учётки.

При этом вы разумеется вольны варьировать какие-то части плейбука через указание переменных: тот самый пример в комментариях про пользователя Bob или Alice. И подставлять в конфиги нужного пользователя.

Отдельный важный вопрос здесь – то, как мигрировать на новую версию операционной системы. См. [схожий вопрос на so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780951/213987).

В общем случае, вам придётся тщательно продумать переход, подготовиться к нему. Могут отсутствовать нужные пакеты, измениться адреса репозиториев, могут поменяться расположение конфиг-файлов, их отдельные параметры. Придётся почитать, что нового, продумать, какие части ваших плейбуков затрагивает.

Однако это настолько удобно, прозрачно и понятно, что процесс переезда становится очень удобным и понятным. Я давно ушёл от практики настройки софта руками – потому что можно даже на следующий день уже забыть подробности разворачивая, а твой рецепт (плейбук) установки - вот он, в гите, всегда с тобой.

Поэтому я весьма рекомендую попробовать если не конкретную систему (chef насколько я понимаю подходит хуже под ваши потребности: он требует установки клиента, который будет периодически опрашивать сервер на предмет не поменялось ли чего в конфигурации), то сам принцип управления конфигурациями, а не утыкаться в прошлый век ("я напишу баш-скрипт", "я скопирую себе конфиг-файлы на флешку и буду каждый месяц обновлять их").

Comment: Смотрите, то что вы написали это круто и удобно, мне реально приятно что я узнал о ansible. И теперь я буду использовать это для управления VDS. Именно ansible, потому что, как я понял, он сводит указания к простым командам и общается с сервером по ssh, в отличие от шэфа, которого нужно ставить на сервер. Но вернемся к моему вопросу, проблема вот в чём: представьте что у вас есть 1ПК, вам нужно установить на него ОС и сконфигурировать её. ОС вы поставили, что дальше? У вас нет второго ПК для конфигурирования первого. Ansible умеет конфигурировать машину на которой установлен?

Comment: Если нет, то проблема очевидна, вы не можете сконфигурировать свою машину. "Но как тогда это должно работать по вашему?" - я устанавливаю некую утилиту, указываю ей на файл конфигурации (например это архив) и утилита начинает устанавливать нужные мне пакеты и настраивать их в соответствии с указаниями, после чего сообщает об успехе и я начинаю пользоваться готовым к работе ПК. Этот файл может быть на флешке или ftp сервере или я могу оставить его на разделе диска, который не буду форматировать.